# How to search between two dates in C# with MS Access

Tags: c#, date, ms-access, between

So for a group project I need to be able to search between two dates "Start_Date" & "End_Date". Both of these fields use one Column from the database called "study_date". Currently I can only search for one date by entering the specified date into either field.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace RRAS
{

    public partial class formRRAS : Form
    {
        public OleDbConnection DataConnection = new OleDbConnection();


        public formRRAS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        //When the form loads it sets the intial combo box RFR item to null
        private void formRRAS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.tblReject_test' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tblReject_testTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tblReject_test);

            cmbRFR.SelectedItem = "";

        }

        //AddRFR method, called in the NewRFRPopup
        public void AddRFR(object item)
        {
            cmbRFR.Items.Add(item);
        }

        //The code for the button that closes the application
        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //This creates the String Publisher which grabs the information from the combo box on the form.
            //Select and Dataconnection are also defined here.
                string Department = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDepartment.Text)? "%" : txtDepartment.Text;
                string Start_Date = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStart.Text)? "%" : txtStart.Text;
                //DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(Start_Date);
                string End_Date = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEnd.Text)? "%" : txtEnd.Text;
                string Anatomy = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAnatomy.Text)? "%" : txtAnatomy.Text;
                string RFR = String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbRFR.Text) ? "%" : cmbRFR.Text;
                string Comment = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtComment.Text)? "%" : txtComment.Text;

                string Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test WHERE department_id LIKE '" + Department + "'" + "AND body_part_examined LIKE'" + Anatomy + "'" + "AND study_date LIKE'" + Start_Date + "'" + "AND study_date LIKE'" + End_Date + "'" + "AND reject_category LIKE'" + RFR + "'" +  "AND reject_comment LIKE'" + Comment + "'";

            //DataConnection connects to the database.
            string connectiontring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb";
            DataConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectiontring);

            //The DataAdapter is the code that ensures both the data in the Select and DataConnection strings match.
            OleDbDataAdapter rdDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Select, DataConnection);

            try
            {
                //It then clears the datagridview and loads the data that has been selected from the DataAdapter.
                database1DataSet.tblReject_test.Clear();
                rdDataAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tblReject_test);
            }
            catch (OleDbException exc)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        } //End of Search button

        //Temporary button thats loads the chart when clicked
        private void btnLoadChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string connectiontring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb";
                DataConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectiontring);

                try
                {
                    int count = database1DataSet.Tables["tblReject_test"].Rows.Count;

                    DataConnection.Open();
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                    command.Connection = DataConnection;
                    string query = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test";
                    command.CommandText = query;

                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        charRejections.Series["RFR"].Points.AddXY(reader["reject_category"].ToString(), reader[count].ToString());
                    }

                    DataConnection.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
                }
            }
        } //end of load chart button


        //This button loads the NewRFRPopup form
        private void addRFRToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewRFRPopup popup = new NewRFRPopup(this);
            popup.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Please* don't use string concatenation to generate the SQL statement. Use a proper parameterized query. Any number of valid characters could be causing an error, eg the comment `I've tried but failed` will break the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
string Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test WHERE department_id LIKE '" + Department + "'" + "AND body_part_examined LIKE'" + Anatomy + "'" + "AND study_date >=#" + Start_Date + "#" + "AND study_date <=#" + End_Date + "#" + "AND reject_category LIKE'" + RFR + "'" +  "AND reject_comment LIKE'" + Comment + "'";
```

Comment: I tried this, whenever I search I get an error that says: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

Comment: String concatenation is the root of all SQL injection evil. Use a parameterized query so that a comment of `'; DROP TABLE tblReject_test ;--` doesn't destroy your database. Or entering a comment like `I've tried but I failed` doesn't crash the application

Comment: if you are storing date is DATE field in the DB table then use # instead of '. See edited answer

Comment: Use cdate(Start_Date) and cdate(End_Date) because they are strings and not dates.  Also, as a fail safe you can cast the study_date as date as well (if it's not a date in db).   `....... "AND cdate(study_date) <= cdate(" + Start_Date + ")  AND cdate(study_date) >= cdate(" + End_Date + ").....`

Comment: Hello all, thank you for the responses.

Unfortunately none of the above options have worked.

@DiscipleMichael, would you be able to put that code into the full select string for me? As when I attempt to use it in it's current state it's just a mess and will not work at all.

Regards,
Aaron

Comment: `string Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test WHERE department_id LIKE '" + Department + "'" + "AND body_part_examined LIKE'" + Anatomy + "'" + "AND cdate(study_date) >=cdate(" + Start_Date + ") AND cdate(study_date) <=cdate(" + End_Date + ") AND reject_category LIKE'" + RFR + "'" +  "AND reject_comment LIKE'" + Comment + "'";`

Comment: The above is just the answer @ssk provided with the cdate substituions

Comment: A good step to see the actual string it's creating is to breakline right after it is set, and check it's value.  If you still get errors, post the value of your string "SELECT" so we can see it without variable names

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response.

Again I tried that line of code and it did not work. Using breakpoints to determine the value of the dates once they are called showed that they were the same as the entered dates.

Comment: get the string from .net and try executing the query in MS Access and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think a couple of others mentioned it here, but don't ever do string concatenation in SQL for your "where" clause.  It's just inviting all sorts of issues.

What you want is Parameters, aka bind variables.  These serve as placeholders -- a way to say, "compile this SQL, and I'll provide you the values later."

Parameters have numerous advantages:

1. They prevent SQL Injection -- however rare and difficult to pull off, this is always a possibility; why invite the risk?  Especially when you data comes from text boxes, you are almost begging for someone to try
2. They make your code so much cleaner.  All of those plus, single quote, double quotes make my head spin
3. You can generally keep your SQL pristine -- copy and paste it right into your SQL editor, without having to prune the nasty characters involved in SQL concatenation.  Okay, so this isn't true with Access, but with other RDBMSs, it makes a big difference to be able to cut and paste
4. They resolve datatypes -- you don't need to put #hash marks# around dates for Access or do anything special for strings (not even quotes) -- see my example below
5. They handle special characters.  For example, if one of your text boxes contained `I think I'll go to the park`, that apostrophe would translate to a single quote which would wreck your query.  With parameters, you don't have to worry about it

Here is an example of a parameterized version of your query:

```
string Select = @"
    SELECT * FROM tblReject_test
    WHERE
        department_id ALIKE @Department & '%'  AND
        body_part_examined ALIKE @Anatomy & '%' AND
        reject_category ALIKE @RFR & '%' AND
        reject_comment ALIKE @Comment & '%' and
        study_date >= @Start_Date and
        study_date <= @End_Date
";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Select, DataConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", txtDepartment.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Anatomy", txtAnatomy.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RFR", cmbRFR.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", txtComment.Text);

DateTime startDate, endDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtStart.Text, out startDate))
    startDate = DateTime.MinValue;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(txtEnd.Text, out endDate))
    endDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_Date", startDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End_Date", endDate);
```

Another parting shot -- the use of text boxes for your dates -- this would be much cleaner if you used a Date/Time control.  The parsing will work, but it's a lot of extra effort for what the control does natively.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_Date", dateTimePickerStart.Value);
```

Oh, and by the way, I think I answered your question about the date being between the start and end dates within this proposed solution.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your useful code. While I don't doubt that it works, I cannot confirm it as when I use it and try to search for a record on my program I get a popup message saying: "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Comment: That usually means it's a typo -- like I created a parameter called `@Department` but then actually bound a parameter named `@Dept`.  I checked the code and it appears, at first glance, that everything matches.  I can mock up a DB and test it to see if I get the same thing

Comment: Well, I'm not sure...  I mocked it up, and it works exactly as expected.  The only other thing I can see that might be different is you are using an .mdb file, and mine is an .accdb.  Out of curiosity, can you switch to the new format and see if it works?

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the delayed response. I have tried using the .accdb format and visual studios keeps telling me that it is an unrecognized database format, which is why I chose to use .mdb in the first place.